# Graphviz [outputorder=edgesfirst] does not seem to work

Tags: visualization, graphviz

I am visualizing a graph with graphviz's sfdp. But the edges are covering the node, which is annoying. I added this attribute [outputorder=edgesfirst] to the graph but it does not seem to work.

Output:
[image]

Source:

```
digraph G {
graph [overlap=false][outputorder=edgesfirst];
0;
1;
2;
3;

.....

330;
331;
0->18 [color=red];
0->325 [style=invis];
2->3 [dir=none];

.....

331->330 [color=red];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set the node's style to filled and add a fillcolor of white, you'll get the nodes appearing on top of the edges.

```
digraph G {
    graph [overlap=false outputorder=edgesfirst];
    node [style=filled fillcolor=white];
    0->18 [color=red];
    0->325 [style=invis];
    2->3 [dir=none];
    .....
    331->330 [color=red];
```

Comment: oh, the default is transparent. Thanks